# embed tag not displaying pdf file on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used embed tag to show a pdf file on my html page and it is displaying the pdf file very well on a desktop and laptop browser but that is not showing the pdf file on moblie and talbets , is there any way I can make them appear on mobile as well . 
Here is the concerned code :

```
<embed src="assets/img/jimbosmenu.pdf" width="900" height="900">
```

Here is the link to live page .
http://jimbosjoint.com/menu

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to use `object`, not `embed`

```
<object data="filename.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
  <p>Your web browser doesn't have a PDF plugin.
  Instead you can <a href="filename.pdf">click here to
  download the PDF file.</a></p>
</object>
```

Comment: I've tried the same without result. It only show the option to download it which i don't want to use it right now. Any other option?

Comment: But, `p` and `a` tag cannot be used inside `object` tag!

Comment: I've tried object, it's not working. Ive tried iframe too but that only gives me a page not found error, although the pdf exists in the specified source..... any idea why?

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Working fine for me in 2020 still.

Comment: not working in 2021. In web mobile, it only show the download option

Comment: not working in 2023

Answer (score 11):

show it from google docs like that:

```
<object width="900" height="900" data="https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://jimbosjoint.com/assets/img/jimbosmenu.pdf"></object>
```

Comment: <a href="assets/img/jimbosmenu.pdf" >download</a>

Comment: blessing, working 2022

Answer (score 2):

`<object>` tag will not display pdf on mobile chrome; The solution is to use  `<iframe>`:

```
<iframe src="filename.pdf" title='SOME_TITLE' />
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<embed>` tag is outdated. Consider using the `<object>` tag. However, it might be a better option to link to the PDF file, so the mobile user can view it in full screen.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution, not the best, but I use this.
Convert the PDF file to JPG. Here is a site where you can make a LONG picture from a more-page PDF. After you can apply overflow: auto; and scroll it.

[Long Pic from Pdf](https://www.workintool.com/pdf-converter/pdf-to-long-image.html)

Comment: This answer does not provide an answer to the question, and would fit better as a comment under the original question.